# Is DLL function called from multithreaded application run on same thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, dll, thread-safety

I have multithreaded application. Now, I have written one function in Windows DLL.
I am calling this DLL function from thread function (called by multiple threads) which is in my application.
So, my question is, does this DLL function also executes on same calling thread?
(And no need to handle multithreading separately in DLL)

Comment: It will run on the same thread as you called the function with. However libraries (dlls) can require you to make ALL calls from the exact same thread. And if the documentation of the library doesn't explicitly state a function is threadsafe then don't make calls to it from different threads either (create one "workerthread" that is responsible for handling all the calls to that library)

Comment: Dlls were around before C++11, which was the first version of the standard mentioning multiple threads. Also creating a thread costs os resources and time, so os/standard libraries leave the creation of a new thread a concious choice for the programmer to make. You can think of calling a dll function the same way as calling any other function. Just be aware that there's some magic happening "under the hood" that allows the linking binary to find the location of logic in the dll, even if the dll (but not the dll interface) is updated after linking.

Comment: Thank you all. Are there any book or links that I can refer for such implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the DLL function will execute on the same thread as the caller. There is no need to handle multithreading separately in the DLL.